# Strict Standards: Non-static method

Tags: php

I got a problem over here, I'm trying to get my scripting better, but I'm getting this error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method DB::query() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Checkin\content\news_index.php on line 2
```

some guy already told me I'm using static and non-static the wrong way, but i really don't get this error.

The error is at a few lines, 2, 3 and 9.

This is my news_index.php:

```
<?php
$pickQuery = DB::Query("SELECT * FROM `cms_picks` WHERE `enabled` = 'true' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6");
if(DB::num_rows($pickQuery) > 0){
?>

                <div class="heading blue">Wat gebeurt er in <?php echo $hotelnaam; ?>? </div>
                <div class="inner news_picks">
                    <?php
                    while($pickFetch = DB::fetch_array($pickQuery)){
                    ?>
                    <div class="pick">
                        <a class="url" href="<?php echo $pickFetch['url']; ?>" ><div class="image" style="background: url('<?php echo htmlentities($pickFetch['image']); ?>') no-repeat; height: 60px; width: 160px; float: left; border-radius: 7px; border: 2px solid #ADADAD;  "></div></a>
                        <div class="text" >
                            <a class="url" style="font-size: 15px;" href="<?php echo $pickFetch['url']; ?>"><b><?php echo htmlentities($pickFetch['title']); ?></b></a><br />
                            <?php echo htmlentities($pickFetch['desc']); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope that someone can help...

Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your `DB` class then you'll see the function `Query` defined as a member function or instance method.  Member functions are called on an instance of the class.  In your case it would be something similar to:

```
$db = new DB();
$db->Query($sql);
```

However, you're calling `Query` statically, i.e. `DB::Query($sql)`.  The difference is, instance variables and methods are called on object using arrow `->` operator and static functions and variables are accessed using scope resolution `::` operator on the Class.

Note: `$sql` used here is a placeholder for your query.

Had your `Query` function been defined static as `static function Query($sql)` in `DB` class then your code would not have complained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which library you are using, but the error seems pretty clear: you should not be calling `DB::Query` through its class name but rather create an object first:

```
$db = new DB( /* whatever parameters the constructor takes, see documentation */ );
// ...
$pickQuery = $db->query("SELECT ... ");
```